# Dotnet Core In Memory Cache - what is the default expiration

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, memorycache

I'm using MemoryCache in a dotnet core C# project. I'm using it store a list of enums that I read out of a collection (I want to store it since it uses reflection to load the enums which takes time).

However, since my collection isn't going to change, I don't want it to expire at all. How do I do that? If I don't set any Expiration (SlidingExpiration or Absolute Expiration), will my cache never expire?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you do not specify an absolute and/or sliding expiration, then the item will theoretically remain cached indefinitely. In practical terms, persistence is dependent on two factors:

1. Memory pressure. If the system is resource-constrained, and a running app needs additional memory, cached items are eligible to be removed from memory to free up RAM. You can however disable this by setting the cache priority for the entry to `CacheItemPriority.NeverRemove`.
2. Memory cache is process-bound. That means if you restart the server or your application restarts for whatever reason, anything stored in memory cache is gone. Additionally, this means that in web farm scenarios, each instance of your application will have it's own memory cache, since each is a separate process (even if you're simply running multiple instances on the same server).

If you care about only truly doing the operation once, and persisting the result past app shutdown and even across multiple instances of your app, you need to employ distributed caching with a backing store like SQL Server or Redis.

Comment: It seems the .NET Core cache does not evict on memory pressure and grows without bounds if no size limit is explicitly set.

Comment: Depends on what bounds you're talking about. If there's no competition for memory, it will expand theoretically up to 100% memory utilization. Practically, that limit will be lower, but I'm not sure where you're getting the idea that it won't evict if there's an actual need to.

Comment: Because .NET Core MemoryCache doesn't actually support automatic eviction on memory pressure. The new recommendation is to determine your own parameters for compaction and to initiate it manually as needed. If you don't do that then you will just keep using up more memory and start paging out data, bringing everything to a crawl.

Comment: Also see here, `CompactOnMemoryPressure` is now obsolete: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.memorycacheoptions.compactonmemorypressure?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: I see. It used to happen automatically, but no longer does. Really sucks when they do stuff like that. I don't really use memory cache (always use Redis), so hadn't realized this had changed. Thanks for the update.

Comment: I think it's for the better. The previous implementation had a ton of issues and relied on an unreliable CLR hack to size objects. Applications designed to use up all available memory should tailor their cache trimming behavior to something that makes sense for that application. The generalized solution provided before just had too many issues in too many situations.

Comment: Yes, this answer is incorrect. The Asp.Net Core changes to the MemoryCache are bad enough that I would argue it is *not a cache*. It doesn't respond to memory pressure so it's just a Dictionary. It should be renamed. Update this answer to reflect the fact there's no memory pressure eviction and I'll reverse downvote.